# Is the past or the present tense correct in this?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I **started** working this morning.

Or should it be

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I **start** working this morning.

?

Comment: Kamil: you might want to look up verbs that can "take ing for the second verb". start, stop, commence, like, love, hate. start working, stop working. You have to memorize them.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably read it in a few different ways (and the context would probably let the listener know your exact meaning here), as it is a somewhat complex sentence, but I read the difference simply as follows:

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I started working this morning.

You have already started working.

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I start working this morning.

You have not started working yet.

Answer (score 0):

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I started working this morning

is correct. "started working this morning" is a past action

> I like that you made it a point to bring me food before I start working in the morning.

is correct, but it means every morning, not just this morning.

> I would like you to make it a point to bring me food before I start working this morning.

is a request about future action.

In all of these the construction "...made it a point to bring me food..." seems a little unusual, a little awkward, but there is nothing wrong with it, and I am finding it hard to explain just why i think it odd.